# How to retrieve Azure Frontdoor Standard/Premium Route/Endpoint/Origin/Origin Group Resource Ids?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-front-door

I'm using the Visual Studio Code Azure Bicep Extension to generate Bicep scripts of existing Azure resources on a subscription.

How do I retrieve the resource IDs of the Frontdoor (CDN) Standard/Premium profile resources via the Azure Portal?

Viewing the Frontdoor Profile page, I can access the resource ID of the profile itself via the left hand menu -> Properties -> Resource Id, however utilizing this in conjunction with the VS Code Extension generates just the code for the profile itself.

Viewing the routes/origin groups etc are rendered in popups/modals on the page, and don't reveal their resource IDs.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came to is actually pretty simple - [decompile your ARM template into a Bicep file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/decompile?tabs=azure-cli) using the Azure CLI.

In my specific case, I navigated to my Front Door/CDN profile, and on the left hand menu, under Automation, I selected Export Template.

After the JSON template is generated, copy it and save it to a file locally or download it.

After [installing the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli), it's as simple as running the following command in the same directory as the file you saved:

`az bicep decompile --file your-downloaded-arm-template.json`

Your Bicep file will appear (should the operation be successful) as the same name as the ARM template, just with a `.bicep` extension.